# Is there any way to publish Android app for testing?

Tags: android, publishing

I have developed only 25% of my app. Now I would like to publish my app so that I can ask my remote tester and friends to test my app. I have no problem to register in google and pay $25 registration fee but I want to know that is there any app verification process on google side? Is there any possibility that they will deny to publish my app as it's not completed yet and not stable also?

One more question guys, $25 registration fee is per app per year or for unlimited time?

Comment: why publish it? just send him the .apk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just send an APK of what you have so far to your friends? You don't have to register with Google at all then, they'll just have to enable the installation of apps from unknown sources.